# Vba DateAdd runtime error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: vba

I am new to vba and i am writing a simple program to calculate time 15 minutes before the current time ,  i know its a very easy program but i getting this error:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

```
Dim time1 As Date
time1 = now
Tex1.Text = time1
Text2.Text = DateTime.DateAdd("n",-15,time1)
```

I am getting this error in last line of the code.

Comment: Is the naming correct? --> Tex1.Text = time1 or must it be "Text1.Text"?

Comment: Time is stored as a fraction of a day (24 hours) so 1 hour is 1/24 and 1 minute would be 1/(24*60) so 15 mins is 1/96 or 0.0104167 and so 15 mins before now is now() - 0.0104167  so Text2 = format(now()-(1/96),"hh:mm") will give you a nicely formated time in your textbox

Comment: @Andre: Namings are correct.